# Does $\{\pi, \mathbb{R}\}$ exist?

Tags: set-theory

I don't know the axiomatic construction of set theory, but I'm asking myself a question :

Does the set $\{\pi, \mathbb{R}\}$ exist?

And $\{i, \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "exists"? This question, as it stands, makes no sense, and I fear it will be closed.

Comment: Has it a mathematical sense ?

Comment: What do you mean by "having mathematical *sense*"? What are you trying to get to by asking this?

Comment: @Arnaud, presumably when you ask a question you have a specific sense in mind... It is on you to explain what you mean.

Comment: It's just for my curiosity. Maybe that the answer will teach me a lot about set theory ! I mean by "having mathematical sense" : "existing in the set theory". We know for example that a set never contains itself.

Comment: @Arnaud There are no particular obstacles to constructing these sets.

Comment: Even more strangely, the sets $\bigcup\pi$ and $\mathcal P(i)$ exist, but have no specific significance, i.e. (in contrast to $\{i,\pi,\mathbb R\}$) it is somewhat difficult to tell what the elements are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the [basic axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#4._Axiom_of_pairing) of set theory is that for any $x,y$ we have that the set $\{x,y\}$ exists, that is, there is a set $z$ whose elements are precisely $x$ and $y$. This holds whether we work in standard set theory (say, $\mathsf{ZFC}$), where *everything* is a set, or in set theories that allow the existence of "primitive" objects (sometimes called atoms, or urelements). Anyway, if your set theory is reasonable enough to formalize mathematical discourse, it will have an official version of $i,\mathbb R,\pi,$ etc, so certainly $\{i,\mathbb R\}$ and $\{\mathbb R,\pi\}$ are sets.

Comment: Of course one could ask whether the "official copy" of $\mathbb R$, as defined within the theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$, "really" is $\mathbb R$, or at least "really" captures our basic intuitions about $\mathbb R$. But such a question is less mathematical and more philosophical.

Comment: In Wikipedia, it is marked that $x$ and $y$ should be sets ! $i$ is not $\{i\}$. Is $i$ a set ?

Comment: In the standard formalization of set theory, everything is a set, including $i$, $-17$, $\sqrt\pi$ and a $7\times 7$ matrix with entries on $\mathbb F_2$. Other formalizations allow us to have objects that are not sets, and then the axioms need to be restated somewhat. If we allow atoms, then pairing, for example, simply says that for any two objects $x,y$, the set $\{x,y\}$ exists. Here, $x$ and $y$ can be sets or "atoms".

Comment: How would be these sets, something like: $\{ \pi,\{\mathbb{R}\}\}$? Because $\pi$ is already one element of  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira $\{\pi,\mathbb R\}$ is a set, and $\{\pi,\{\mathbb R\}\}$ is another set. That $x\in y$ does not mean that $x,y$ cannot be together as elements in a set.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they exist. Furthermore, since $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$, we can conclude that $\pi \neq \mathbb{R}$, at least in ZFC. So $\{\pi,\mathbb{R}\}$ has two elements. However, there's no such guarantee that $i \neq \mathbb{R}$. So all we can say is that $\{i,\mathbb{R}\}$ has between 1 and 2 elements. Of course, if we knew how we had defined $i$ and $\mathbb{R}$, we would probably have a definite answer to whether $i = \mathbb{R}$.